# MS Access Int and Sql Server Big INT

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, types

We have a database in Sql Server 2005 with MS Access as front end. The back end was initially in access and later transferred to Sql server.

One of the fields in the tables in sql server has data type int with primary key. Now I believe int data type of access has limitations of 32767 being the largest integer.

The field has auto-increment set with primary key and it has reached the figure 32767.

I tried changing the data type from int to bigint but on the front end access started throwing all kind of errors. One of the error being "Data Type Mismatch".

Thanks
Yogi.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server

- smallint is signed 16 bit as per your comments (-32768 to +32767)
- int is signed 32 bit, so -2.1 billion to +2.1 billions
- bigint is signed 64 bit so -huge to +huge

You could get this from MSDN *very* easily. No need to "believe"

More importantly, you didn't need to make any changes in SQL Server and you didn't need to generate these errors. The errors probably come from foreign key errors or such that depended on this column being int.

Anyway, if it *is really* smallint and you've reached 32767, you could just change the seed and increment from (-32768, 1) to use the other half of the range...

Comment: In other words, SQL Server SMALLINT=Jet/ACE INTEGER and INT = LONG INTEGER. Jet/ACE has not data type corresponding to BIGINT, so you have to use various workarounds when using it as PK in a SQL Server table.